# I am new to distributed cache, and confused about choosing the better option and how to handle the cluster

Tags: caching, redis, hazelcast, distributed-caching

My application receives requests (varying from 1 to 500) from multiple clients using socket connection. These requests are xml files that are to be stored in distributed cache for further consumption by external application. There is no database in this application. Also the client requests could be simultaneous, hence the cache should handle multi threaded application. Could some one advise me on below questions:

•   How to choose if internal cache within application is enough or set up external cache cluster? (does it cause any overhead ? if the application is destroyed then do we loose cache?)

•   Which distributed cache has to be chosen?(application is completely java based spring boot)

•   Application will not be deployed in cloud, but can we choose any cloud cache cluster? like Cache as a Service (CaaS)

•   How many nodes cluster is required? How do we decide this?

Comment: Your question is overly broad and really many questions. It would be better to break them into separate questions.

Comment: I have break down the questions.

Comment: As @aaronR also stated, your questions are too generic. You need to ask them in different Stackoverflow questions and be more specific (provide more details) on each of them.